# Calculating time range in Excel

Tags: excel

Assume I have such data:

```
29.10.2014 19:00    30.10.2014 7:30
29.10.2014 23:00    29.10.2014 18:00
30.10.2014 9:00 30.10.2014 23:15
31.10.2014 18:49    1.11.2014 7:15
```

How to get that time which is between 22:00 to 6:00. Like first example row 29.10.2014 19:00  30.10.2014 7:30 whole work time is 12:30 (12,5h) and work time between 22-6 is 8:00 (8h). How to get this 8h. Used some searches and find sumproducts, sumifs, countifs but didn't handle them by myself.

Comment: this question is very unclear. please be direct about your question

Comment: When I start working at 19 o'clock and finishing my job like at 7, how to calculate this time which is between 22 to 6 in excel?

Comment: you just made it more unclear.. what do 22 and 6 have to do with it

Comment: 22 to 6 is 40% more money time and 19-22 and 06-08 is also more money time, want to get this time to calculate with coficents later those hours/minutes

Comment: if you can't even explain your problem properly how are we supposed to help you?

Comment: I dont understand what question are you asking? Starting work at 00:02 and finishing 8:25. Whats the work time between 22 to 6? Like  how many time you work in this time range?

Comment: "starting work at 00:02 and finishing 8.25. what's the work time between 22 to 6." are we supposed to understand that?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to calculate the time between 06:00 and 22:00, so assuming start time/date in `A2` and end time/date in `B2` use this formula to get decimal hours

`=(MOD(B2,1)< MOD(A2,1))*(22-6)+MEDIAN(6,22,MOD(B2,1)*24)-MEDIAN(6,22,MOD(A2,1)*24)`

That also assumes that end time will either be the same day or the next, is that right?

To get 22-6 time just calculate total time minus the above, so if the above is in `C2` use this in `D2`

`=(B2-A2)*24-C2`

I assume that your second example is an error because start time/date is after end time/date